# how to change the uppercase into lowercase in html

Tags: html

how to transfer the uppercase letter to lowercase letter ?.

for example : THIS IS IS A LETTER to lowercase like This is a letter .
I do not want to change the full sentence ,just change except first letter rest all are want to change.

Answer (score 3):

```css
p:first-letter {
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>i am devat karetha</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

In HTML, try this,

T`<div style = "text-transform: lowercase"> IS A LETTER</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I've always used a simple javascript function for cross-browser functionality - this works anywhere:

```
function sentenceCase(S)    //1st upper,rest lower - S=string
{
if (!S) S="";
return S.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + S.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a quick javascript function:

If this is an HTML form (so naive):

```
<input type="text" id="test"><input type="button" id="ok">
```

You could use the following function:

```
document.getElementById('ok').onclick = function() {
  var first = document.getElementById('test').value.substr(0,1);
  var rest= document.getElementById('test').value.substr(1);
  document.getElementById('test').value = first.toUpperCase() + rest.toLowerCase();
}
```

The second example works "live" during insertion:

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="test">
```

JS

```
document.getElementById('test').onkeyup = function() {
  this.value = this.value.substr(0,1).toUpperCase() + this.value.substr(1).toLowerCase();
}
```

Get a live preview: [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/oldMammuth/pcvv5rrz/1/)

Notice how you definitely should do it using two substrings (using *substr(start[, end])* method), because to date there are only *toUpperCase()* and *toLowerCase()* methods for JS strings; 
a *toSentenceCase()* would be handy in this case, but for what I know it does not exist...